# div width is not working?

Tags: css, html, width

I have a problem with content from a div, for example if I put a table inside of a div and set a width `(width:200px !important)`for that div the table it will overwrite that div. So how is possible to keep all content inside that div?

fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ebG9N/45/

Comment: div width can not be smaller than the table width, you want table to resize to 200px?

Comment: By the way, all the `!important` part does is override `width` properties defined elsewhere for the given div. It does NOT give the `width` any more power.

Comment: Give width for the style as width:400px !important;
    border:2px solid yellow;
    background:#eaeaea;
    height:300px;

Answer (score 2):

You set the header to `white-space: nowrap;` therefore, the browser is unable to break the headers, so the width of the table will be bigger than the container div.

You can set, `overflow: hidden;` to cut the overflowing parts, or `overflow: auto;` to create a scrollbar, but without them it's the correct rendering.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions.

i) IF you want to STRICTLY contain table WITHIN div then [overflow:auto;](http://jsfiddle.net/ebG9N/57/) is the way to go.

ii) BUT if you change your mind and want to WRAP div to the width of table then.
[display:table;](http://jsfiddle.net/ebG9N/58/) is the way to go.

Generally its bad idea to contain wider element within explicitly known less wider element.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `overflow:auto;` in the css of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just expect it to somehow fit within a div of any size you wish. What you can do is, at least allow the browser to scroll (`overflow: scroll`) it using:

```
div.divano{
    width:200px !important;
    border:2px solid yellow;
    background:#eaeaea;
    height:200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

You may also use `oveflow: hidden`, but it would just hide the parts that are not visible. Also, `overflow: scroll`, will always show a scroll bar (with or without clipping). You can use `overflow: auto` to specify that the content should be scrolled only if clipping occurs.